How can i manage boolean flags in Django?
Can somebody explain, which best practice should i use for managing flags in my Django Models, that will be serialize in DRF
I have this model:
class Project(models.Model):
* Logic *
is_free = models.BooleanField(default = True)
 is_paid = models.BooleanField(default = False)

 is_free_or_donate = models.BooleanField(default = False)

How should i manage this flags in Django?
Should I use model methods for this purpose to incapsulate logic within model? Or maybe overwrite save methods and do it there? I appreciate for having tips about best practices

You "manage" (whatever that means in your context) it like any other field just with the exception that it take boolean values. There's not much special about this type.

I don't really get what you mean with "manage". How does a boolean field differ from the other fields you are managing?

I agree that my question isn`t correct, sorry for that. I meant that How can i change flags depends on other flags in my model. For example client choose is_paid for project. but flag is_free stay True by default and i have to change this. But where can i do this efficient way? Within model in methods or in signals for example. Which practice will be better for this?

Typically you avoid that fields depend on another, and try to make these orthogonal, such that the items that depend on the other fields, are no longer fields, but properties/computed fields.


How can i change flags depends on other flags in my model. For example client choose is_paid for project. but flag is_free stay True.

One usually tries to make fields that are orthonormal, in other words, can freely change from each other. Fields that (fully) depend on other fields are then defined as properties or computed fields.
So here one could use:
class Project(models.Model):
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def is_free(self):
        return not self.is_paid
Making two fields that (fully) depend on each other will introduce a lot of problems: you need to think of every possible scenario where you change one of the two and how that impacts the other(s). It also means you use more storage, and if another program makes changes to the database, it can still go wrong.
If fields to some extent depend on each other, that typically means there is a more fundamental field possible. For example you could have a voucher that is no longer valid if the due_date expires, or when someone actively disables it.
Then instead of using:
# wrong
class Voucher(models.Model):
    due_date = models.DateField()
    expired = models.BooleanField()
you use:
# right

from datetime import date


class Voucher(models.Model):
    due_date = models.DateField()
    invalidated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def expired(self):
        self.due_date < date.today() and not self.invalidated
